# GetWindowText Can't Handle TradeMark Symbol

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, encoding

```
HWND ForeWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
wchar_t WindowTxt[1024] = { L'\0' };
GetWindowTextW(ForeWindow, WindowTxt, 1024);
wprintf(L"%s\n", WindowTxt);
std::wstring Str(WindowTxt);
std::wcout << L"Wnd: " << Str << L"\n";
```

Using the above code to get the window of skype which is "Skype™" i get the output:

> "Skype?"

(the wcout line fails to execute)

1) Why is the wide character version of GetWindowText unable to handle this character

2) Why does std::wstring fail to parse the wchar_t array and then print it to the console

Comment: It is not a problem with GetWindowText.  Consoles are stuck in the 1980s and have the user-friendliness of a stone brick.  You'll have to switch to better encoding, like utf-8, use SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8).  And change its font.

Comment: Writing to a file instead of printing to a console produced the exact same issue.

Comment: What did the debugger tell you?

Comment: Writing to the console, and not setting the streams locale was the issue, you guys got me looking at output rather than code and i quickly figured out the locale issue, thank you.

Comment: Also look at `MessageBoxW()` or `OutputDebugStringW()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMD consoles don't handle Unicode well.  Send the output to a file and open it in and editor, and I suspect you'll get the actual character you expect.

Comment: This was the issue, also note that when i at first attempted to write to the file i did not set the locale, causing the same issue. After setting the locale use std::wofstream.imbue(std::locale("")) it worked as it should. Thank you.