# How to get Unicode window title correctly

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I create Win32 console application that does a simple task: it enumerates captions of all windows. Everything works well except one little point – “non-English” titles are returned as “GDI+ Window”.

I do not know how to retrieve such captions in a right way.

For example, I have window with the caption: Hello Мир. However, GetWindowTextW returns “Hello GDI+ Window”

There is my program code (simplified):

```
    BOOL CALLBACK nextWindow ( HWND window, LPARAM param )
    {
        int i = GetWindowTextW ( ... );
        wprintf ( ... );
        return true;
    }

    int main ()
    {
        WNDENUMPROC func = &nextWindow;
        LPARAM someValue = 0;

        BOOL result = EnumWindows ( func, someValue );
        return 0;
    }
```

There is my Project Settings:
[Visual Studio Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVSHT.png)

Thank you!

Comment: I think you went a little too simple in your example.  How about something that compiles? For bonus points you could have it create a window that shows the problem too.

Comment: I had to fill in the blanks, but this is a screen shot of a message box generated from essentially your program with the string you provided used as a filename in Notepad. I'd say the problem exists in the code you have not shown or the specific circumstances you have not described.. http://imgur.com/a/h01pn

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527078/getwindowtext-cant-handle-trademark-symbol because he is using wprintf and probably not setting the console's locale to UTF8 or something similar that can handle the wide characters - writing it to a file would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, you were most helpful!

In my case, I just need to change translation mode using the following code:

```
    _setmode ( _fileno ( stdout ), _O_U8TEXT );
```

See more details in article by [Michael S. Kaplan](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2008/03/18/8306597.html).

Problem solved.